# D3 V4 Basic example not working

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to get one of Mike's Bar Chart examples working. [The bar chart example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) shown https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304 does not give any errors, just does not display any content. Am I missing something obvious?

I have set up a plnkr, and as you can see, no joy there either. http://plnkr.co/edit/LPS6U7u1PuP2YdPPvanH?p=preview

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

The tsv you have added in the plunk is not really a tsv, so you need to correct that.

**Problem 2**

you have written the javascript inside the `style` tag...that is the reason it will not execute.

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yg415bueUxfCnAp8ykiR?p=preview)